# Implementing a 202 ACCEPTED - Retry-After behaviour with RSocket and Project Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, rsocket, rsocket-java

I'm implementing a tipical use case in which a client asks for a resource that will be asynchronously generated. Thus, a resourceID is generated and returned right away:

```
1. CLIENT ---(POST /request-resource)--->  SERVER
2. SERVER (Generates resID, launches async process) ---(202 Accepted - resID)---> CLIENT
```

At this point there is a background task in the SERVER, that will eventually produce a result and store it in a database associated to the resID. The CLIENT would be asking for the resource periodically, retrying until it is available:

```
3. CLIENT ---(/resource/resID)--->  SERVER (checks in Postgres using reactive driver)
4. SERVER ---(404 - Retry-After 5)---> CLIENT
5. CLIENT ---(/resource/resID)--->  SERVER (checks in Postgres using reactive driver)
6. SERVER ---(200 - JSON Payload)---> CLIENT
```

I though RSocket would be a perfect fit in order to avoid this endless CLIENT retry until the resource is available (steps 3. on).

**Which interaction model would be more suitable for this problem and how could I implement it?**

Consider a repository as follows: `ResourceRepository.Mono<Result> getResult(String resID)`

If I chose a **request/response** interaction model I'd be in the same case as before. Unless there was a way to have a Mono that retried until there is a result. Is this possible?

With **request/stream** I could return results like `Flux<Response>` with response.status=PROCESSING until the query to Postgre returned a result, then the Flux would have an element with response.status=OK and the Flux would complete. A maximum time would be needed to finish the Flux without a result in a configured period. In this case how could I orquestate this?

I would need to create a Flux, that emits periodically (with a max period timeout), having an element with no result when the repository returns an empty Mono, or the actual value when te repository has it, completing the Flux.

Comment: Why return the resourceId? Just wait until it's done and return a Mono of the result

Comment: How do you implement a query against a Postgres reactive repository that retries until there’s a result then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you show some code?

Comment: I would be calling a repository until the background task finishes inserting a value. I need to retry the repository query call until it has some result. I think you gave me a hint, I could use the repeatWhenEmpty operator https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#repeatWhenEmpty-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: What writes to the db? You shouldn't have to poll anything if you control the codebase. Just have whatever function/service saves to the db pass a message on a queue/stream that you pick up and then return.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. The server (service1) upon the initial request publishes a message to a queue. Another service (service2) will process it and finally write to the database. That’s why service1 would be polling, because another service will asynchronously be the one updating the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem using RSocket with a RequestResponse interaction model that waits until the resource is available in DB. The key was to use the `repeatWhenEmpty` operator:

```
    @MessageMapping("request-resource")
    fun getResourceWebSocket(resourceRequest: ResourceRequest): Mono<Resource> {
        return resourceService.sendResourceRequestProcessing(resourceRequest)
    }
```

```
    override fun sendResourceRequestMessage(resourceRequest: ResourceRequest): Mono<Resource> {
        val resourceId = randomUUID().toString()
        return Mono.fromCallable {
            sendKafkaResourceProcessingRequestMessage(resourceId, resourceRequest)
        }.then(poolResourceResponse(resourceId))
    }
```

```
    private fun poolResourceResponse(resourceId: String): Mono<Resource> {
        return resourceRepository.findByResourceId(resourceId)
                .repeatWhenEmpty(30) { longFlux ->
                    longFlux.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                            .doOnNext { logger.info("Repeating {}", it) }
                }
    }
```